# Axios > Express.router – Update(.put) method returning 404

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, axios

I am trying to finish building the last CRUD method of my App. (C, R and D) all done. But updating seems to be proving bothersome. I have a function which combines the object ID with the new content to update with. I am getting 
`Error: Request failed with status code 404`
printed to the console.

I think I'm failing to reach the database item using the ID.

### Function which gathers the data and initiates the request

```
  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const data = {
      id: this.props.sid, //someuniqueid
      body: {
        name: this.state.name, //foo
        details: this.state.details, //bar
        content: this.state.content, //baz
      },
    }
    api
      .updateSnippet(data)
      .then(result => {
        this.setState({
          name: '',
          details: '',
          content: '',
          message: `'${this.state.name}' has been created`,
        })
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({
            message: null,
          })
        }, 2000)
        console.log('UPDATE DATA SUCCESS!')
      })
      .catch(err => this.setState({ message: err.toString() }))
  }
```

### api.js - uses axios to fire the request (this may be where I am failing).

```
import axios from 'axios'

const service = axios.create({
  baseURL:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? '/api'
      : 'http://localhost:5000/api',
  withCredentials: true,
})

const errHandler = err => {
  console.error(err)
  if (err.response && err.response.data) {
    console.error('API response', err.response.data)
    throw err.response.data.message
  }
  throw err
}

export default {
  service: service,

  updateSnippet(data) {
    console.log(data.id) //someuniqueid
    console.log(data.body) //{name: "foo", details: "bar", content: "baz"}
    return service
      .put('/snippets' + data.id, {
        data: data.body,
      })
      .then(res => res.data)
      .catch(errHandler)
  },

}
```

### Snippet.js (schema)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const snippetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'The snippet name is required'],
    minlength: 1,
  },
  details: {
    type: [String],
    default: [],
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
  },
})

const Snippet = mongoose.model('Snippet', snippetSchema)

module.exports = Snippet
```

### Relevant route in "routes/snippets.js" - This could also be where I am falling over

```
router.put('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body)
  Snippet.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.body.id,
    {
      name: req.body.name,
      details: req.body.details,
      content: req.body.content,
    },
    { new: true },
    function(err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('we hit an error' + err)
        res.json({
          message: 'Database Update Failure',
        })
      }
      console.log('This is the Response: ' + response)
    }
  )
})
```

Comment: what does console.log(req.body) it log ?

Comment: @ibtsam nothing, it doesn't fire.

Comment: Your route must be start with: router.put("/:id" ...
Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the id in the url, so you need to parse it from req.params.id.
I also returned response.

routes/snippets.js

```
router.put("/:id", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  Snippet.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    {
      name: req.body.name,
      details: req.body.details,
      content: req.body.content
    },
    { new: true },
    function(err, response) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("we hit an error" + err);
        return res.json({
          message: "Database Update Failure"
        });
      }
      return res.send(response);
    }
  );
});
```

Also you need to update this line  in api.js. Just add / after snippets

```
   .put('/snippets' + data.id, {     => 
   .put('/snippets/' + data.id, {
```

Comment: I was sure you had it then. I've added `"/:id"` however am still getting `Error: Request failed with status code 404`

Comment: does your request hits to this route?

Comment: @Neil I found another problem and updated answer, can you check?

Comment: Hey, I get `PUT http://localhost:5000/api/snippets/5d9a6f611c9d440000d9205a net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` returned

Comment: @Neil So we hit the route? what does console.log(req.body) ?

Comment: @Neil if you know postman, can you try with postman first? And what is the result of  console.log(req.body)?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The browser console.log doesn't fire. My command line returns `ROUTER[object Object] This is the response: null`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200560/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-neil).